# Bridge NSB over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, nservicebus

I am trying to publish a WCF service that sends to a NSB host. I have looked at the WebServiceBridge example in the NSB samples but cannot figure out how to use the NServiceBus.WcfService class in the WCF counterpart.

I have found out that I can have my service interface inherit one or more IWcfService < TRequest, TResponse >, but since the service class cannot inherit multiple base classes (WcfService), is it possible to have one service implementation serve several message types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frederik,

The WCF Bridge for NServiceBus (like the Web Service Bridge) is designed to be one WCF service = one message type. So, I'm afraid that the answer is no, though you can always write your own bridge (based on the code in the base class) that will support more than one message type.

Hope that helps.
-- Udi Dahan